# In Wxpython How do i Insert an image into an Ultimatelistctrl column?

Tags: image, list, insert, wxpython, controls

I am curious as to how one would go about inserting an image from a specific directory into a specific row/column in an Ultimatelistctrl

```
MainFrame.ultimatelist = ULC.UltimateListCtrl( self.panel , agwStyle = wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES , pos = (10,100) , size = (1240 , 520) )
    #-------------------------------------------------------------
    MainFrame.FirstColumn = ULC.UltimateListItem()
    MainFrame.FirstColumn._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT | ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    MainFrame.FirstColumn._image = []
    MainFrame.FirstColumn._format = 1
    MainFrame.FirstColumn._kind = 1
    MainFrame.FirstColumn._text = ""
    MainFrame.ultimatelist.InsertColumnInfo( 1 , MainFrame.FirstColumn)
    MainFrame.arrowicon = wx.Image( "arrow.jpg" , wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()


    MainFrame.ultimatelist.SetImage( 0 , MainFrame.arrowicon )
```

Cheers, It has been really bothering me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the magic is in the wxPython demo. You need to create an UltimateListCtrl.PyImageList. Then add wx.Bitmap instances to it. Next, you need to tell your UltimateListItem() object to use an item from the image list. In the demo, look for "info._image" to see how it's done. You can download the wxPython demo from the wxPython website.